# Is it possible to schedule a calendar resources using ics file?

Tags: google-calendar-api

When i add resources in ics file, google parse it correctly and show resources under resources tab (Rooms etc) BUT it did not book the resources with the corresponding time from ics file.

Google Calendar events can be book using ics file but Is it possible to book resources calendar using ics file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible for a local ICS file to be able to modify resource calendars, etc. Just your local calendar.

Comment: can you provide some links or other resources you might have looked into to back your answer?